# How to design a table in servicenow

Tags: html, bootstrap-4, angular-ui-bootstrap, servicenow

I am new to front end designing, I want to design a table as shown below in Servicenow Service portal:

[image]

I am trying from my side but I am not getting the correct design

```html
<div class="panel panel-body">
  <h2>Book Rooms v1</h2>
  <table border="2" class="table table-striped m-b-lg">
    <tr>
      <th>Country</th>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>End Date</th>
    </tr>
 
  </table>
```

I want to have a fields in white color as book_ticket, x:y.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am elaborating the answer.

1. To use Bootstrap and bootstrap-javascript, we have to include it in the file. Thus I have included the Bootstrap 4.4 and in the end of code, I have the added the JavaScript file. (Refer [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/getting-started/introduction/) for more)
2. Then to design a table, we do it using the html tags. Then to add the styles, we can include the Bootstrap [classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/content/tables/).
3. Refer the documentation [page](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/getting-started/introduction/) for more.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Template</title>

    <!-- bootstrap 4.4 -->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <style>
      tr:nth-child(even),
      thead {
        background-color: #bdc2c7;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <table class="table  table-responsive-sm table-bordered border-dark">
        <caption style="caption-side: top;">
          Books Room v1
        </caption>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th scope="col" colspan="3">Passenger</th>
           </tr>
           <tr>
            <th scope="col">Serial Number</th>
            <th scope="col">Title</th>
            <th scope="col">End Date</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Book Ticket</td>
            <td>x:y</td>
            <td>r:s</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Book Train</td>
            <td>p:q</td>
            <td>t:u</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Book Train</td>
            <td>p:q</td>
            <td>t:u</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Book Train</td>
            <td>p:q</td>
            <td>t:u</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>

    <!-- Bootstrap js ,popper js and jquery  -->
     <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script
      src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**[For More](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/content/tables/)**

**Update**

i have edited the code ...

Comment: it looks good and but the code is very huge and contains lot many href links, if you dont mind can you please help me in explaining does these all required honestly i have no idea what that code is talking about :(

Comment: @AbdulAzeez, i have included the some explanation. Please mark it as answer if it helps

Comment: @AbdulAzeez, Watch the youtube video - https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL4cUxeGkcC9jE_cGvLLC60C_PeF_24pvv

Comment: One last question sir, in the first row i want to have a single column row that tells like Passenger Name, it should be full row without columns. can you please help me how to do that

Comment: @AbdulAzeez,sorry for late replying. Could you please elaborate ypur question

Comment: @AbdulAzeez, i hv edited the code..please check now

Comment: I sorted down tedd than you so much.. But i am facing another issue with background image which is not responsive to the mobiles. if possible can you please look at the code which i have written here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60830277/how-to-render-background-image-in-mobile?noredirect=1#comment107627286_60830277

Comment: @AbdulAzeez, i saw your question. But unable to understand the question. please tell there ..what is the requirement ,,..so that everyone can help you

Comment: Actually with below below i am able to add a background image: 
body {
 background-image: 
      url("https://www.rafflesmedicalgroup.com/images/default-source/default-album/wuhan-virus-background.jpg?sfvrsn=2");
 background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
 
}
When i see in the chrome it looks good the same image when i open in mobile the image is not getting decrease based on the size i mean the width or size of the image is fixed with that i cant see the full image

Comment: @AbdulAzeez, So you want the mage to be responsive ?

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
    <div class="panel panel-body">
      <h2>Book Rooms v1</h2>
      <table border="2" class="table m-b-lg">
<thead>        
<tr>
          <th>Serial Number</th>
          <th>Title</th>
          <th>End Date</th>
        </tr>
     </thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
   <td>Book_ticket</td>
   <td>x: y</td>
   <td>p: q</td>
</tr>
<tr class="bg-white text-dark">
   <td>Book_train</td>
   <td>r: s</td>
   <td>t: u</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
      </table>
```

Comment: Hi @John Kreedam, 
Thank you that works very nice but sir if you dont mind can you please me in making the look-end field some more attractive ? I know its not a right way to ask but i apologize sir since i never had my hands on frond end it takes so difficult to think in attractive designing :(

Comment: Hi @AbdulAzeez, I can help you if you can tell me exactly what you need to do.
If I answer your question, kindly make my answer as the selected answer.