# How to render background image in mobile

Tags: html, css, responsive, servicenow

On the web page i have a background image which is not rendering properly on mobile view

```css
body {
 background-image: 
      url("https://www.rafflesmedicalgroup.com/images/default-source/default-album/wuhan-virus-background.jpg?sfvrsn=2");
 background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
 
}
```

In Web page it is working perfectly but not in mobile

Comment: you might need different size images if you are going to apply that to body. I think

Comment: What do you mean by "properly"? You might want to set `background-repeat: no-repeat`. Also the `cover` value resizes the image so that the whole area is filled with the image, which is therefore cropped. Please explain what result you want to achieve.

Comment: I have a image added as per above code which is working fine, when i see in mobile the image is minimizing it is at the same size with which i cant see the entire image

Comment: Please refer to this: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp